# Trying to Load More than One Asteroid on Screen

Tags: c#, xna

Im attempting to create an Asteroids Game using C# XNA.
When loading the program, however, it only loads one asteroid instead of the 5 that i believe i am specifying in the code.

```
 public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        // Creating Random Origin Coordinates For Asteroids
        randX = random.Next(500, 1180);
        randY = random.Next(500, 984);

        // If There Are Less Than 5 Asteroids On The Screen, Create More Until 5 Are Present
        if (asteroidsList.Count() < 5)
        {
            asteroidsList.Add(new Asteroids(Content.Load<Texture2D>("asteroid big"), new Vector2(randX, randY)));
        }
    }
```

Now within this code, i think that im saying if there are less than 5 asteroids on the screen, to add another asteroid on the screen.
If this is not what the code is saying, an explanation would be appreciated
Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line that creates the asteroid

```
asteroidsList.Add(new Asteroids(Content.Load<Texture2D>("asteroid big"), new Vector2(randX, randY)));
```

is only executed once.

Use a loop like so:

```
while (asteroidsList.Count() < 5)
{
    randX = random.Next(500, 1180);
    randY = random.Next(500, 984);
    asteroidsList.Add(new Asteroids(Content.Load<Texture2D>("asteroid big"), new Vector2(randX, randY)));
}
```

EDIT: Updated the while-loop example to randomly position each of the asteroids.

Comment: Thank you for that. Thought it might've been something like that, but when i tried doing it before, i had all sorts of errors, but that works now. Cheers

Comment: No problem, glad to be able to help you. A bit of free advice: You probably want to avoid hardcoding the numbers of asteroids and the boundary position used in the random. Define a constant. E.g. `private const int MinAsteroids = 5` and use it : `while (asteroidsList.Count() < MinAsteroids)`

Comment: It might be more efficient if you assign the `Texture2D` of the asteroid outside the loop, other wise it will load the texture from the disk every time. This isn't really important, but when you have 100 asteroids it will run faster isntead.

Comment: What @joppiesaus said, instead a `private static Texture2D asteroidSprite` should be loaded, and then a loop should be made to add the asteroids.